# Why is there Unreachable code detected in C# - Nested ternary operation into if-else statement

Tags: c#, linq

before that, Im a beginner in c#. I had change nested ternary operations into independent statement but when I change it to if-else statement, it says that it is unreachable code

here are the lines that I had problem with

```cs
FlowLineSize = sumOfAllWells,
NoOfWell = _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocacbornType == "Gas"
    ? _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.GasFlowlineSize
    : _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocacbornType == "Oil"
        ? _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.OilFlowlineSize
        : 0
```

what is the syntax format to put if else statement after the `sumOfAllWells,`, I already tried putting if statement after it and it say unreachable code

Edited:

here is the full code,

```cs
public BrainSubseaJumperInputDTO FillInputDTO(ProjectInfoDTO projectInfoInput = null, BrainConceptsInputDTO conceptInput = null)
{
    var sumOfAllWells = conceptInput?.ConceptDCDetailsInputDTO
        .Sum(x => x.OilProducerWell + x.GasProducerWell + x.WaterInjectorWell + x.GasInjectorWell) ?? 0;
    return new BrainSubseaJumperInputDTO()
    {
        FlowLineSize = sumOfAllWells,
        NoOfWell = _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocacbornType == "Gas"
            ? _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.GasFlowlineSize
            : _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocacbornType == "Oil"
                ? _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.OilFlowlineSize
                : 0
    };
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you tried.

Comment: That's not valid C# code. It looks like part of something else, an anonymous type perhaps? Or `Select`? We can't guess why this can't be reached without the full method code. If the entire query can't be reached, it doesn't matter what's in the `Select` expression

Comment: Since there is a bug in the independent statement with if-else, we must see it. Please insert the code.

Comment: When using strings, you should use string.Equals. From a readability standpoint, nesting ternary operators like this does not show your code's intentions. I would use a switch statement or nested ifs.

Comment: `NoOfWell = _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocarbonType switch { "Gas" => _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.GasFlowlineSize, "Oil" => _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.OilFlowlineSize, _ => 0 }`. As we keep repeating `_brainConceptDCDetailsInput`, consider making this a method or property of whatever type that is, and since we're switching on a type string, also consider if a `LineSize` member in a base class or perhaps a dictionary of instances wouldn't serve better.

Comment: @JimmyV You should, but only because you should be using the overload that takes a `StringComparison` parameter. If you don't pass a parameter other than the string to be compared, it's exactly the same as using `==`, because the `==` implementation calls the same underlying implementation as `Equals()` does. So it's important to point out that you should be passing a `StringComparison`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, indeed. Always use the StringComparison parameter, I did leave that out of my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>If this was valid code:</strike> After the edit, it makes more sense ...

```
FlowLineSize = sumOfAllWells, // <== Typo here? No, it's part of something bigger
NoOfWell = _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocacbornType == "Gas" ?
                            _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.GasFlowlineSize :
                            _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocacbornType == "Oil" ? 
                                 _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.OilFlowlineSize 
                                 :0
```

then that ternary abomination would roughly translate to

```
if( _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocacbornType == "Gas")
{
    NoOfWell = _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.GasFlowlineSize;
}
else
{
    if(_brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocacbornType == "Oil")
    { 
        NoOfWell = _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.OilFlowlineSize;
    }
    else
    {
        NoOfWell = 0;
    }
}
```

assuming there is a `NoOfWell` declared.

But as pointed out in comments: There are better (i.e. cleaner, more readable) ways to express this.

For example switch expressions:

```
NoOfWell = _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.HydrocarbonType switch 
{ 
    "Gas" => _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.GasFlowlineSize, 
    "Oil" => _brainConceptDCDetailsInput.OilFlowlineSize, 
    _ => 0 
}
```

If you can make `HydroCarbonType` a class then this maybe could be a property of that.

If you could make it an Enum, you could use Dictionary and ExtentionMethods ...

---

After seeing the full code, you could also make the logic part of a DTO Builder / Factory ...

```
static BrainSubseaJumperInputDTO FromBrainConceptDetailsInput( 
                                     int sum, 
                                     WhateverTypeThatIs input )
{
    return new BrainSubseaJumperInputDTO(){
        FlowLineSize = sum,
        NoOfWell = input.HydrocarbonType switch 
                   { 
                       "Gas" => input.GasFlowlineSize, 
                       "Oil" => input.OilFlowlineSize, 
                       _ => 0 
                   }
    };
}
```

That would boil down your code to

```
public BrainSubseaJumperInputDTO FillInputDTO(ProjectInfoDTO projectInfoInput = null, BrainConceptsInputDTO conceptInput = null)
{
    var sumOfAllWells = conceptInput?.ConceptDCDetailsInputDTO
                                     .Sum(x => x.OilProducerWell + 
                                               x.GasProducerWell + 
                                               x.WaterInjectorWell + 
                                               x.GasInjectorWell) 
                                     ?? 0;
    return FromBrainConceptDetailsInput( sumOfAllWells, 
                                         _brainConceptDCDetailsInput);
}
```

Comment: "Ternary abomination"? Now I feel guilty. :-)

Comment: @Steve Not every ternary is an abomination.